# Why is it that $\overline{a}\langle u,v\rangle + a \overline{\langle u,v\rangle} = 2\mathfrak{Re}(\overline{a}\langle u,v\rangle)?$

Tags: linear-algebra

Why do we have that if $\langle,\rangle$ is an inner product on an inner product space $V$ where $V = \mathbb{F}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, that $$\overline{a}\langle u,v\rangle  +  a \overline{\langle u,v\rangle} = 2\mathfrak{Re}(\overline{a}\langle u,v\rangle)?$$
Thank you! I dont understand why we have the "$\mathfrak{Re}$" part in front!

Comment: this is just $\bar u v + u\bar v = 2\Re (\bar u v)$. This is because $\bar u v$ and $u\bar v$ are conjugates.

Comment: For future reference: use `\langle` and `\rangle` for angle brackets and `\overline` for a wide bar.